# Why does changing a value in one input change the value in another input too?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to learn and experiment with React hooks. For a small test project I want to update a calendar grid when the user changes the display mode or changes the date.

Here is `Calendar.jsx`. The state is stored here. `date` and `setDate` are passed as props to `CalendarDatePicker`.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import CalendarDisplayMode from './CalendarDisplayMode';
import CalendarDatePicker from './CalendarDatePicker';
import CalendarGrid from './CalendarGrid';

const Calendar = props => {
    const [date, setDate] = useState(props.date);
    const [mode, setMode] = useState(props.mode);

    return (
        <div className="bg-light border border-dark rounded p-1">
            <CalendarDisplayMode mode={mode} setMode={setMode} />
            <CalendarDatePicker date={date} setDate={setDate} />
            <CalendarGrid displayDate={date} displayMode={mode} />
        </div>
    );
}

Calendar.propTypes = {
    date: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date).isRequired,
    mode: PropTypes.oneOf(['day', 'week', 'month', 'year']).isRequired
}

export default Calendar;
```

Here is `CalendarDatePicker.jsx`. When any of the inputs change `setDate` is called and passed the new date. This should update the state in `Calendar`.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const CalendarDatePicker = ({date, setDate}) => {
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    const day = date.getDate();

    const handleYearChange = event => setDate(new Date(event.target.value, month, day));
    const handleMonthChange = event => setDate(new Date(year, event.target.value - 1, day));
    const handleDayChange = event => setDate(new Date(year, month, event.target.value));

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="display-year">Year</label>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    id="display-year"
                    name="display-year"
                    className="form-control form-control-sm"
                    min="1"
                    value={year}
                    onChange={handleYearChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="display-month">Month</label>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    id="display-month"
                    name="display-month"
                    className="form-control form-control-sm"
                    min="1"
                    max="12"
                    value={month}
                    onChange={handleMonthChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="display-day">Day</label>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    id="display-day"
                    name="display-day"
                    className="form-control form-control-sm"
                    min="1"
                    max="31"
                    value={day}
                    onChange={handleDayChange} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

CalendarDatePicker.propTypes = {
    date: PropTypes.instanceOf(Date).isRequired,
    setDate: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default CalendarDatePicker;
```

But I'm observing strange behavior. If I increment or decrement the number in the year field, the month field increments its value. If I increment or decrement the month field none of the other fields change values (as expected). If I increment or decrement the number in the day field, the month field increments its value. If I increment or decrement the number in the day field enough the month field rolls over (from 12 to 1) and the year field also increments its value.

Can anyone explain what might be happening here and how to fix it?

Comment: honestly, at this point, why not just write a normal component instead of trying to use a functional one?

Comment: Define normal..

Comment: I have added an answer that outlines how to dynamically handle days in a month, etc.. For example, if you change the month to February, you will only be able to select up to 28 days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    const handleYearChange = event => setDate(new Date(event.target.value, month, day));
    const handleMonthChange = event => setDate(new Date(year, event.target.value - 1, day));
    const handleDayChange = event => setDate(new Date(year, month, event.target.value));
```

In `handleYearChange` and `handleDayChange` you are passing `month` which is actually `date.getMonth() + 1` - you need to do `month - 1`.

that's why your month increases by 1 when year or day changes.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** *handling it this way, you can also change the total for days in a month, etc.. without having to hard code it to 31. Just an example of how this design allows you to be flexible.*

I personally don't understand why you are passing `setDate` down to the child component.. I do not see the point in this or what you gain from doing it..

In my opinion the issue stems from how you are handling your design.

Each time something changes, `const year`, `const day`, `const month` all run again.. this is where you should be using `state`.. Just pass in a `date` as a prop, then handle all changes to that date local to the `DatePicker` component... allowing the child to reach up to the parent and change it's state directly feels odd to me.

Something like this is how I would handle this - it feels much cleaner.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const CalendarDatePicker = ({date, onDateChange}) => {
    const [year, setYear] = useState();
    const [month, setMonth] = useState();
    const [day, setDay] = useState();
    const [daysInMonth, setDaysInMonth] = useState();
  
    useEffect(() => {
      setYear(date.getFullYear());
      setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
      setDay(date.getDate());
    }, [date])
  
    useEffect(() => {
      let dim = getDaysInMonth(month, year);
      setDaysInMonth(dim);
    }, [month, year]);

    const handleYearChange = event => {
      let nd = new Date(event.target.value, month, day);
      setYear(nd.getFullYear());
      onDateChange(nd);
    }
    const handleMonthChange = event => {
      let nd = new Date(year, event.target.value - 1, day)
      setMonth(nd.getMonth() + 1);
      onDateChange(nd);
    }
    const handleDayChange = event => {
      let nd = new Date(year, month, event.target.value);
      setDay(nd.getDate());
      onDateChange(nd);
    }
    
    function getDaysInMonth(month, year) {
      return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="display-year">Year</label>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    id="display-year"
                    name="display-year"
                    className="form-control form-control-sm"
                    min="1"
                    value={year}
                    onChange={handleYearChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="display-month">Month</label>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    id="display-month"
                    name="display-month"
                    className="form-control form-control-sm"
                    min="1"
                    max="12"
                    value={month}
                    onChange={handleMonthChange} />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="display-day">Day</label>
                <input
                    type="number"
                    id="display-day"
                    name="display-day"
                    className="form-control form-control-sm"
                    min="1"
                    max={daysInMonth}
                    value={day}
                    onChange={handleDayChange} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


const Calendar = props => {
    const handleDateChange = event => {
      console.log('You can change the `Calendar` during this event when the date changes...', event);
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="bg-light border border-dark rounded p-1">
            <CalendarDatePicker date={props.date} onDateChange={handleDateChange} />
        </div>
    );
}

render(<Calendar date={new Date(Date.now())} />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want the calendar to change when the date changes. For example, if you change the month from September to October, I want the calendar to be re-drawn for October. That happens in `CalendarGrid` in my code (I did not include its code but you an see it referenced in `Calendar.jsx` above). How would you go about passing the date from `CalendarDatePicker` to `CalendarGrid` if the state is not stored in the parent component (`Calendar`)?

Comment: I would move all logic/state up to the calendar component and just pass down month, day, and year props. Essentially, `CalendarDatePicker` would be purely presentational.

Comment: Where would you place the event handlers for when the year, month, or day change? Would you keep them in `CalendarDatePicker` or pass them down as props from `Calendar`?

Comment: @J.Owens I would have to mess with it some more, but I did make some changes in my answer.. I feel like this is the best way to handle it. **Open your console after changing the year/day/month** - It's not perfect, and needs some work - but you get the idea...